# error LNK2019 and error LNK1120

Tags: c++

```
//opgave 8.6.1(1)
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "krypto.h"
#include "krypto.h"
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    krypto data;

    cout << "skriv her:";
    data.hentdata();

system("pause");
return 0;
}






//Krypto.h
#pragma once
class krypto
{
public:
    krypto();
    void hentdata();
private:
    char data;
};





//krypto.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "krypto.h"
using namespace std;

krypto::krypto()
{
}

void hentinput(){
    char data;

    cout << "Skriv dit input: ";
    cin >> data;
    cout << data;
    }
```

I can´t find the error! can anyone help?
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall krypto::hentdata(void)" (?hentdata@krypto@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _wmain C:\Users\LAB\Documents\steffen\c++ opgaver\bogen\opgave 8.6.3(1)\opgave 8.6.3(1)\opgave 8.6.3(1).obj    opgave 8.6.3(1)
 
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\LAB\Documents\steffen\c++ opgaver\bogen\opgave 8.6.3(1)\Debug\opgave 8.6.3(1).exe  1   1   opgave 8.6.3(1)Error    2

Comment: Where is the implementation of `void hentdata();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
void hentinput()
{
    char data;
    ...
}
```

To this:

```
void krypto::hentdata()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Except the missing function isn't named `hentinput`.  It's more likely that renaming it to `void krypto::hentdata()` would work, although it's hard to say if that is the correct solution but it would fix the link error.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Yep, I agree. It also shows very little effort trying to solve the problem at hand. I fixed the answer, but will consider to remove it due to that issue...

Comment: @SteffenKjærThomsen: You're welcome. Try to write your code in a little more organized manner, it will help you in the future.